# Password protected pages (without username) in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, passwords

I am working on a rails-project where you can create photo-albums. I would like the creator of an album to enter a password that is needed to access this album. Then, when users want to view it, they have to enter a password. I dont need a full user management system, and I would prefer that users do not have to enter a username with their password (which is the case when I use `authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic`).
What is the best way to handle this scenario?

Comment: So, a user doesn't have to be logged in to create and/or put a password on an album?

Answer (score 0):

1. Store the fact that the user has successfully entered the key-word in the session
2. Check for that fact in a before_filter, redirect to a form for them to enter their key
3. Redirect back to the album after they enter their key.

Sort of an old-school authentication, but without a username.